# How to test permission file with bash

Tags: bash, file, permissions

How do you test permissions on files using bash ? And how does it work ? Does it look for owner's permissions only or all of them (owner, group, others) ? I used -r and -w to test permissions on some files but I got some inaccurate responses.

Here is what I did :

```
[root@server1 ~]# cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

FILE="$1"
 
[ $# -eq 0 ] && exit 1
 
if [[ -r "$FILE" && -w "$FILE" ]]
then
    echo "We can read and write the $FILE"
else
    echo "Access denied"
fi


[root@server1 ~]# ll file*
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root 1152 Jun  2 18:24 file1
-rwx------. 1 root root    3 Jun  6 20:35 file2
-r--------. 1 root root    3 Jun  6 20:35 file3
--w-------. 1 root root    3 Jun  6 20:35 file4
---x------. 1 root root    3 Jun  6 20:35 file5
----------. 1 root root    3 Jun  6 20:35 file6
[root@server1 ~]# 
[root@server1 ~]# ./script.sh file1
We can read and write the file1
[root@server1 ~]# ./script.sh file2
We can read and write the file2
[root@server1 ~]# ./script.sh file3
We can read and write the file3
[root@server1 ~]# ./script.sh file4
We can read and write the file4
[root@server1 ~]# ./script.sh file5
We can read and write the file5
[root@server1 ~]# ./script.sh file6
We can read and write the file6
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use user root for that.

Comment: i get "Access denied" for file3 - file6

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing essentially wrong with your script. You are executing it as **root** so you **do have** permission to read and write, in fact, root has permission to do anything!

Check this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117236/150151) and you will see that even suppressing the permissions, root user can have access to them. Your output is correct. If you look into the man page of the [test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) command, you can see that the `-r` and `-w` flags test if the file exist and in addition permissions to read and write respectively are granted to the **user executing the command** (both of them since you use a logical *and*).